# How do I Bind observableCollection of strings to a listBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an observableCollection instance, I'd like to bind it to a list, and give the user the ability to change the strings in this collection directly.

The current implementation is as follows:

```
class container
{
    public OBservableCollection<string> data {get; set;}
    public container() { data = new ... }
}
...
var instance = new container();
listBox.ItemsSource = instance.data;
```

and for the XAML:

```
<ListBox>
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding}" MinWidth="50"/>
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I add any string to that list an error appears, "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.". I tried the path value to be "." since I am targeting the same source value, but the binding failed.

Please advise,

Comment: i know you have tried but did you do this -- **path=.**

Comment: @Muds you mean like: Text="{Binding path=.}", sure I did, I said so in the question

Comment: You'll have to create a data item class that exposes the string as a property. A Binding can change its source property, but it is not able to replace a string in a collection.

Comment: @Clemens, thank you, but I think if we can access the value directly it would be better as a matter of design.

Comment: Yea, Clemens is right, you need to have a wrapper class around your strings... let me kno if you need sample tho

Comment: I have tried that before, no sample needed, thank you, but I am searching for a way to access the values directly, I think binding supports that, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx

Comment: well strings are immutables, I don't think there will be any easy way to do what you want to do ..

Comment: @Clemens could you please post this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer if I cannot find an answer for my specific conditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A WPF Binding can not replace an element in a collection.

You will have to create a data item class with a string property

```
class Item
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class Container
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Data { get; set; }
}
```

that can be two-way bound:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" MinWidth="50"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```